# Как называется программная среда разработки для ЯП Scala?

Tags: scala

Стал изучать язык программирования Scala

Скачал с их сайта интерпретатор языка.

Но вместе с тем возник вопрос,как называется программная среда в которой я могу писать мелкие приложения на Scala

В книге Scala для нетерпеливых сказано только про сам интепретатор но про среду разработки ни слова.

http://horstmann.com/scala/install/ - здесь описаны способы установки, я установил у меня теперь ссылка на документацию.

А вот само приложение где бы начать писать я не вижу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как таковой среды разработки, предназначенной для языка Scala нет, однако для большинства популярных сред разработки существуют плагины:

- [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) для среды разработки [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Может поставляться в сборе как единый продукт
- [IntelliJ IDEA Community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) в процессе установки позволяет установить плагин для Scala. По качеству это пожалуй один из лучших плагинов для Scala на данный момент
- [Scala plugin для Netbeans](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/get_started_with_scala_in) существует возможность добавления поддержки Scala в Netbeans, по моему субъективному ощущению работает намного хуже первых двух вариантов, но если очень нравится Netbeans работать можно.
- [Режим Scala для Emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScalaMode) добавляет поддержку в Scala и Sbt в Emacs

Answer (score 4):

Среда с вполне предсказуемым названием [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Я пишу на scala в Idea Intellj community edition. Для scala есть плагины в этой ide